# Xamarin Forms HttpClient GetAsync Fails in iOS Only

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a very simple REST query to our WebAPI back end (used by a number of applications) and it works fine under Android and Windows but in iOS it fails with an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. In the code below, both moHttpClient and loUri are instantiated. I've tried wrapping the call to GetEmployeeRecord in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread but that doesn't help either. I have upgraded to the latest stable version of Xamarin in Visual Studio and on my Mac. Why is it working in the other OSs but not iOS?

```
    private async void btnTest_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await GetEmployeeRecord();
    }

    private async Task GetEmployeeRecord()
    {
        try
        {
            var loUri = new Uri("https://my.website.com/mobile.webapp/api/employees?key=6c6f2c06-a444-4e54-bd77-b5f594c29910");
            var loResponse = await moHttpClient.GetAsync(loUri);
            if (loResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var lcJson = await loResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                await DisplayAlert("Employee", lcJson, "OK");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                DisplayAlert("Get Employee Record", ex.Message, "OK");
            });
        }
    }
```

Using a breakpoint at the GetAsync line, both moHttpClient and loUri are instantiated. However, mousing over GetAsync gives a message that GetAsync is an unknown member.  How can that be?
[image: Mouse over GetAsync]

I just checked and it seems this Unknown member occurs with Android too.  But with Android it actually executes.

Comment: I am getting 404 on URI you provided. What is moHttpClient ? Also you have celf-certs on your web site, that can be the problem too. If you want us to test please provide correct URI

Comment: That is not my web site, I just put that in to mask the actual address for security reasons.  There is nothing wrong with the URI, it works with Android and Windows.  I suspect I need to somehow set something in the iOS project to allow network/internet access.  The code is in the PCL.

Comment: Then put breakpoint on your exception and check what object is null. I cannot help more if I cannot run it and see what is null

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned before.  It is the GetAsync that fails.  Both moHttpClient and loUri are instantiated.  During a break, mousing over GetAsync says the method does not exist.

Comment: I just added a screen clip from the mouse over/break point.

Comment: I checked the breakpoint with Android and it also says Unknown member: GetAsync.  Strange.  Even stranger, it works in Android.  So, it must be something else in iOS.  Is there some sort of setting in iOS that has to be set to allow network access?

Comment: Check that you have Nuget of System.Net.Http installed in ALL your projects. Also what security your server has? SSL, TLS? Self-signed certs?

Comment: I tried to install and it only installed in the Android project.  The PCL attempt came up with this error:  Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.  The reference in the PCL is verion 4.0 it seems.

Comment: what about iOS project? Did you install it there?

Comment: Can you share your project, so I can take a look on packages and try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: You can try Microsoft.Net.Http which supports PCL but if you are using HttpClient only in platfrom specific code then System.Net.Http should work too

Comment: Coincidentally I tried installing Microsoft.Net.Http before I came back here and saw your comment.  I only installed it in the PCL because that is where the code is.  IT WORKS!!!  Now it is working so whatever comes standard with Xamarin Forms (or PCL base stuff) doesn't work for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the http query to work for iOS I had to install the NuGet package Microsoft.Net.Http in the PCL project, which is where the code is running.