# Xamarin.Forms application throws NullReferenceException only in iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms Portable application that runs fine in Android but always crashes in iOS.

I get this error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object at App.ListJson+<GetPodcasts>d__2.MoveNext () [0x0004e]
```

It occurs at this piece of code, on the second line:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(REDACTEDSTRING).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I've tried fiddling with the HttpClient implementation settings for the iOS project but still get the same error.

Comment: I would *assume* you using a non-secure URL  on iOS and have not white-listed it...

Comment: What would constitute as non-secure? I am using an HTTPS url on a server with TLS 1.2 and GlobalSign verification.

Comment: I *assumed* wrong (http://), but since you are using TLS 1.2, are you using a native IOS HttpClient and Apple's TLS (both assigned in iOS Build options). Also whats the reasoning to using `ConfigureAwait`ing..

Comment: I eventually stumbled upon a solution from another question, after sifting through at least 30 threads :P.  The ConfigureAwait is from the code samples I've been learning from (I'm new to C#).

Answer (score 0):

The answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40877285/4244342) solved my problem.

To reiterate it here:

Installing the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package into the base project will fix the issue.