# Xamarin Forms Visual Studio 2015 HttpClient requests not working on iOS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm rather new to Xamarin Forms/ Visual Studio but here is my current situation.
I have a Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio with Android, iOS, and Windows Phone subprojects. I have the following function Login:

```
    public async Task<Tuple<bool, object>> Login(LoginCredentials credentials)
    {
        var loginUrl = apiUrl + "/login";
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        try
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("start of try block");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(loginUrl, content);
            Debug.WriteLine("this will not print on iOS");
            string bodyStr = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // code that does stuff with successful response
            } else
            {
                // code that does stuff with bad response
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
            return new Tuple<bool, object>(false, e.Message);
        }
    }
```

As you can see from the `Debug.WriteLine()`'s, an exception is thrown on the line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(loginUrl, content);
```

The exception is `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

However, this exception only occurs on iOS. Android and Windows Phone can both successfully make this request.

My first assumption was that it was **Apple's ATS** which would make sense since my server is just a dev instance not using https. So I pasted in

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
     <true/>
</dict>
```

to the iOS project's Info.plist. Still no luck.

I also read a question elsewhere that said to make sure Visual Studio on Windows and Xamarin on the Mac are both up to date which I have made sure of as well.

Also `apiUrl` is not `http://localhost` I am using the IPs on my local network (since the Mac and iOS simulator are running on a different machine) which I have confirmed are correct.

If I had to guess at this point, I would say it's still something with the ATS settings not being set properly but I've been unable to confirm this. Not sure where to go from here. I'll continue to debug and add updates but any help would be very much appreciated.

## Update:

As suggested by [Oleg Bogdanov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6592023/oleg-bogdanov), my client instance is not instantiated properly only when running iOS.

When debugging iOS:
[image: iOS HttpClient Debug]

When debugging Android:
[image: Android HttpClient Debug]

Now the task becomes figuring out why this is occurring on iOS. Here is the `client` initialization code. I have tried both where it currently is and where it is commented.

```
public class API
{
    public HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public string apiUrl = "http://myApiUrl";

    public API()
    {
        //this.client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<Tuple<bool, object>> Login(LoginCredentials credentials)
    {
        // login function code
    }
}
```

I'll keep debugging this and post another update when I have any new developments. As usual, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that `client` is instantiated when you try to `Post` your request?

Comment: Yes sure it is. Unless for some reason it would be on Android and Windows and would not be on iOS

Comment: still its your client instance that is null, check what causes it to be null

Comment: @OlegBogdanov thanks for this I've updated the question with new info now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40813125/xamarin-forms-httpclient-getasync-fails-in-ios-only/40877285#40877285).

I ran NuGet `Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http` to the Portable project and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any with ATS. I have created one POC using *localhost* and *shared local server*. Please check following code which is working for my POC

For POST request

```
try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/RegisterDevice");
        string data = "{\"username\": \"ADMIN\",\"password\": \"123\"}";
        var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        Util.HideLoading();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"Success");
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(@"Fail");                
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
```