# HttpClient PostAsync causes System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I am working on a Xamarin cross platform project that talks to a web service. The general form of my service calls follows the following pattern:

```
var clientQuery = new MyClientsQuery(param1, param2);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientQuery);
var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();
response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(ServiceURL, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

This usually works fine, but after making a few calls during the execution of the app, PostAsync generates the exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range.  Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index

I suspect that I am running into some sort of connection limit, but I can not find any documentation in System.Net.Http that indicates when I should be disposing of objects or any other clue.

Why is this happening?

Comment: That exception is likely coming from the webservice you are calling. Are you sure you are providing valid parameters?

Comment: Yes, the parameters are valid.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge, PostAsync will not throw an ArugmentOutOfRangeException . You may be seeing the inner exception returned by the web service you are calling

Comment: Can you post a full stack trace for that exception?

Comment: The "full" stack trace really isn't all that full.  This is all that shows when the exception is raised  0xB in UIKit.UIApplication.Main at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79,4 C#
  0x3B in UIKit.UIApplication.Main at /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/7beaef43/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63,4 C#
> 0x8 in CSOSA.iOS.Application.Main at C:\Code\CsoApp\CSOSA\CSOSA.iOS\Main.cs:17,13 C#

Comment: @RobertLynch There was a question yesterday about the same bug, also IOS, I think you should checkout the Xamarin github issue list

Comment: @Fals Thanks, but I searched back several days for Xamarin issues on github and did not see anything related.

Comment: @RobertLynch heres the question, I investigated also, but I have no clue about the issue, perhaps occur only with specific version of Xamarin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623073/xamarin-forms-visual-studio-2015-httpclient-requests-not-working-on-ios

Comment: It looks like an issue on the XAML binding side of things. Are you using a ScrollView?

Comment: @Stuart Yes, I am using a ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right with your connection limit. The way I am solving this is to end the previous client connections I have. Once I did that, I stopped getting this error.

For others getting this error, see if you have a lot of other http_clients you have created and end the connections if you can.